# Warning "switch"

Tags: php, switch-statement

I'm stuck with a small warning/error.

This is the errore:
Notice: Undefined index: la in ****/layout/header.php on line 10

```
//select language
if (isset($_GET['la'])) {
$_SESSION['la'] = $_GET['la'];
header('location:'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
exit();

}
//language
switch ($_SESSION['la']) {
case 'en':
    require('lang/en.php');
break;
case 'it':
    require('lang/it.php');
break;
default:
    require ('lang/en.php');
break;
}
```

The problem is in the "switch". It all works but how can I fix the warning? 
I tried in some ways, but I went into ball!

Answer (score 2):

> Notice: Undefined index: la

It means an index that you are using in condition its not defined.

**Solution**:

In your code you are missing to start your session, you need to start session at top level as:

```
session_start(); // add on top.
```

And for undefined index you need to declared session index in default.

```
$_SESSION['la'] = "";
```

**Modified code:**

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['la'] = "";
if (isset($_GET['la'])) 
{ 
   $_SESSION['la'] = $_GET['la'];    header('location:'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); 
   exit(); 
} 

//language 
switch ($_SESSION['la']) 
{ 
   case 'en': require('lang/en.php'); 
   break; 
   case 'it': require('lang/it.php'); 
   break; 
   default: require('lang/en.php'); 
   break; 
}
```

Comment: @maxhb this will overwrite if condition is true..

Comment: @maxhb if u r downvoter than read my comments :p

Comment: Yes, removed comment, probably I'm still a little bit sleepy ;-)

Comment: @maxhb no issue brother.. U can also edit my answer if u have any suggestion

Comment: Thanks for Your Help , l ' notice disappears but does not work the change of language.

Comment: @marco its require('lang/en.php'); remove space

Comment: The alert disappears , but it does not work

Comment: @marco print_r($_SESSION); exit; before switch case. And show me the result

Comment: Well u r using `lang/en.Php` in default... So I suggest u can define in default as `$_SESSION['la'] = "en";`  @marco

Comment: Unfortunately nothing , thanks again for your help!

Comment: Include language file in default for testing I hope issue in yur other file @marco

Comment: The warning is about the switch line , it is not that I have something wrong with the syntax ?

Comment: @macro last test .... if($_SESSION['la'] == "it"){ include("lang/it.php") ; } else { include("lang/en.php") ;    }